# Python how to wait for asynchronous MQTT message within REST request

Tags: python, django, rest, asynchronous, mqtt

I am developing a REST service in Django, when request is received in server a MQTT message is published and response is received in a topic. MQTT communication is asynchronous, but REST is synchronous, I am wondering how can I wait inside REST request for a MQTT asynchronous event. I was thinking about registering all MQTT responses in a database and inside REST make a polling to DB during a maximum of 30 seconds for example, but I dont now whether this is the best solution.

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])    
def getvalue(request):

    topic = "send/784980/566734/9227445/foo/foo/01/send"
    msg = 'SJDUEHRYT756'

    logger.info('Topic: ' + topic + ", msg: " + msg)

    if connected == False:
        errorMsg = '{ "error":"No MQTT connection available" }'
        logger.error(errorMsg)
        return HttpResponse(status=500, content=errorMsg, content_type="application/json")

    mqttResult = client.publish(topic, msg, 0, False)
    logger.debug("MQTT request published with id " + str(mqttResult[1]))    

    // here I should get MQTT response for sending it back

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}), content_type="application/json")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    logger.debug(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
```

Comment: That all sounds fairly horrible. Could you turn it around - have an MQTT client subscribed to the topic,  when MQTT message comes in this client makes a REST call into DJANGO?

Comment: Flow is client request -> server -> mqtt -> server -> client response, what do you mean with "turn it around" ?

Comment: "turn it round" instead of django explicitly waiting for the response, when the response comes this client calls into django and that triggers the next step, maybe that's handling the data in the response. So: client request->server->mqtt->device And then that's the end of that action, then device->mqtt->client adapter->server for the response.

Comment: @BlackBishop did you manage to find the solution for this? Me too having same situation.